# Regular expression for matching time in military (24 hour) and civilian (23:59) format

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, jquery-inputmask

I would like to create regex for validate times for military and civilian.

I just found this for military time.

> ^([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$

I need to create pattern for **start time** and **end time** for military and civilian both.

For example, I would like to match time in the following formats in textbox like.

[**EDITOR PLEASE DO NOT EDIT THIS MY BOLD EXAMPLE**]

- **10:30-19:30**
- **1030-1930**
- **10-19**

How can validated in JavaScript?

Please help/suggest me to find the pattern

[image]

Comment: What did you tried? BTW, do you understand, what the regex you provided means? It is easy to modify it to achieve what you want.

Comment: Sorry Sir, i don't know how to make it for both validation.
 `^([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$` this one only for single time for example **1200** but my requirement is military and civilian both can we set in textbox same as start time to end time.

Comment: You can combine larger regular expressions into a single expression using `+`. Using this trick you could write a good expression for the military variant, and another unrelated expression for the civilian format.

Comment: @C-Otto Huh...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.

```
^(?:[01]\d|2[0-3])(?::?[0-5]\d)?-(?:[01]\d|2[0-3])(?::?[0-5]\d)?$
```

It's basically two of yours demanding a hyphen in between. It also makes the minutes optional (by having them in an optional non capturing group `(?:...)?`.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Dh7qE3/3).

Comment: Just do not forget to use anchors in order not to match `ABCE19:00-21:00MOREHERE`.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your super guidance. @ClasG

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Noted Sir